# I need to look back last month data if data in current month is NULL and if last month also null, then one month more earlier

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to join 2 queries based on Month We have month date as well month ID in database.
I want to join Month ID of 1st Query with month ID of Previous month of Second Query. For this purpose, After getting final output in 2nd query, I renamed month column of second query to match with month name of 1st query.

Like if 1st query has cost for Feb 2023, the 2nd query will have relevant cost in Jan 2023. I renamed Jan 23 as Feb 23 and then joined both queries.

Now problem is some times we do not have data in Jan 2023. So we need to look back for Dec 2022 or if Dec 2022 is also NULL, then we need to look back Nov 2022 and so on.

I can join both query on Month ID but cannot look back if current month (after changing name from Jan 2023 to Feb 23) is data in NULL.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for sample data that demonstrates the problem; the expected output for that sample data; and **YOUR** attempt at a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join to retrieve the "latest available row" on the related table or subquery.

For example:

```
select a.*, c.*
from a
outer apply (
  select *
  from b
  where b.month_id <= a.month_id - 1
  order by b.month_id desc
  fetch first 1 rows only
) c
```

For example if table `a` is:

```
 MONTH_ID  NAME      
 --------- --------- 
 50        month 50  
 51        month 51  
 52        month 52  
 53        month 53  
 54        month 54
```

And table `b` is:

```
 MONTH_ID  OTHER
 --------  -----
 49        other 49
 50        other 50
 53        other 53
```

The result is:

```
 MONTH_ID  NAME      MONTH_ID  OTHER    
 --------- --------- --------- -------- 
 50        month 50  49        other 49 
 51        month 51  50        other 50 
 52        month 52  50        other 50 
 53        month 53  50        other 50 
 54        month 54  53        other 53
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/mONwsk_S).